# Trouble installing package with Composer

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I am trying to install [tplaner/when](https://packagist.org/packages/tplaner/when#v2.0.0) package using composer:

The install runs fine, however, when I inspect the installed components, the class `When` is missing some methods that are shown in the source file on `github` and referenced to in readme (for example, `getOccurences`).

I tried writing manually the version in `composer.json` as:

```
"require": {
        "tplaner/when": "2.*"
    }
```

...but to no avail.

Probably I am doing to some rookie composer mistake :)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you compared the source in the `vendor` folder with the GitHub sources. If you do so, make sure you compare to the right Git version tag.

Your Composer installed version `2.*` so you need to compare to git tag [`v2.0.0`](https://github.com/tplaner/When/blob/v2.0.0/src/When.php). I assume you compared to the (development) `master` branch.

If you need functions that are not in version `2.0.0` then the only possible way is to wait until they become `stable` with the next release or switch to the development branch `dev-master` in your Composer:

```
"require": {
    "tplaner/when": "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: That was it - thanks. Just frustrated that the methods are included in the release documentation but not in the actual package for that version.

Comment: Yes, on GitHub you always need to look at the right branch/tag. Even the documentation is different on the branches.